I am having a problem with a project with astro and tailwind

You can see the code in my github repo,
The problem is that i want the image to be the height of the images to be the full with of the screen and the psicosmith image to be above the background image, but when i zoom it the psicosmith image move.
This is the code

        <header class="h-full">
        <figure class="flex   h-full p-0 m-0 ">
        <Image class="h-full w-fit relative z-1" src={Background} alt="Logotipo" />
        <Image class=" h-full w-fit relative right-36"  src={PsicoSmith} alt="Foto de Smith Quintero" />
    </figure>

     </header>


     and this is the layout 
     <!doctype html>
     <html lang="es" class="w-full h-full">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <meta name="description" content=" Bienvenido/a a la plataforma de terapia online de Smith Quintero. Encuentra apoyo profesional y compasivo para tus necesidades de salud mental. Nuestra psicóloga licenciada ofrece sesiones de terapia personalizadas para ayudarte a enfrentar los desafíos de la vida. Da el primer paso hacia la sanación y reserva tu sesión hoy mismo."/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" initial-scale="1"/>
        <meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/favicon.svg" />
        <meta name="generator" content={Astro.generator} />
        <meta itemprop="specialty" content="Psicólogos en línea, Psicólogo online, psicólogos por chat.">

        <meta name="keywords" content="psicosmith, psicologa, terapia, salud mental, psicologa Smith Quintero, psicologos en linea, psicologos online, terapia online, depresion,    ansiedad.">

        <title>{title}</title>
    </head>
    <body class="box-border m-0 p-0 w-full h-full">
        <slot />
    </body>
    </html>

I try to use z-index but it didn't work
